# Logical issue of how to get if the user has liked an image swift 2

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm trying to make a simple photograph app with those tables in Parse.com

table Users

- id
- Name
- email

table Follows

- id
- follower (pointer to User)
- followed (pointer to User)

table Images

- id
- image (file)
- uploader (pointer to User)

table Likes

- id
- likedImage (pointer to Images)
- whoLikedIt (pointer to User)

So I have his logic. If User1 likes the image of User2 there is a row inserted in the table Likes. All good till now.

But if the User1 closes the app and opens it again, I would like to show a red heart (exactly as in Instagram) to the image cell if he liked it.

The problem I that if I do the query inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`
to see if the `currentUser` and the id of the images matches somewhere at the table `Likes` it will not be good for the UX because if he has 100 images it will get slow, eventually.

So my question is, is there any smart way to make the query and change the image of the cell instantly ???

I've thought that when the app opens (and the user is logged in) I can make a general query at the table Likes and search for the currentUser id at the column `whoLikedIt` and make an array with all the id's of the images from column `likedImage`. Then inside the

```
cellForItemAtIndexPath
```

I can check if the image's id is inside that array change the liked image to the red heart, else leave it as it is.
With this way, am I going to gain more speed in my app ???

Or you can suggest any other way?? 
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: do you save the data locally, or do you send a remote request for every row?

Comment: @JohnnyAW in my case i make a request in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath ` but you think i should save them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you download user-related data on login and save it locally. So you can access it for rendering UI. In this specific case I would download ID's of his liked images and store it in a `Set`. Now you can check, if he liked that 1 Image in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

But be aware, you might need to update your local data at some point. Push Notifications would be useful for you in that case

Comment: The speed of loading the images (in that case) will be faster than doing the query from parse, right?

Comment: the speed of "downloading" the image will be still the same, but you will save 1 network-query (is-Liked-Query) in this case

Comment: this is exactly what im trying to do :) thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to show the user what pictures he "liked", best way to do that is to create a table linked with your user that contains all id pictures he liked.

This way you don't charge too much your picture objects (in case a pic is liked 1M times), and you can easily retrieve and check your datas for each user.

Comment: regarding a parse.com video about relations, the least good thing is to make a array column with objectId's inside the array and then query in that array. But i dont think that my app will get any big so your idea is ok i think. Have you tried it?